# Hide rows in table A that appear in table B

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

I have Table (Employees) A:

```
+----+---------+
| ID | NAME    |
+----+---------+
| 1  | ROBERT  |
| 2  | JAMES   |
| 3  | RICHARD |
| 4  | KANYE   |
| 5  | DYLAN   |
| 6  | JOHN    |
| 7  | JEAN    |
| 8  | LOKI    |
| 9  | ADAM    |
+----+---------+
```

And Table (Employees) B:

```
+----+---------+
| ID | NAME    |
+----+---------+
| 1  | ROBERT  |
| 2  | JAMES   |
| 3  | RICHARD |
| 4  | KANYE   |
| 5  | DYLAN   |
+----+---------+
```

Those people are my "employees". The names from table B are all the employees on my database and the names from table A are all the employees that I've assigned to project n°1.

I would like to HIDE all names in Table B that already appear in Table A because I don't want to re-assign the same employee to project n°1.

How can I resolve this using jQuery?

Comment: you want it to be sorted at the client side?

Comment: Hmm, do you have any previous attempts to share with us? I strongly suggest you try to solve the problem yourself first, as you learn a lot more that way.

Answer (score 0):

a clientside check would be:

```
function compareLists(listA, listB){
 var resultList = [];
   listA.forEach(function(itemA){
     listB.forEach(function(itemB){
        if (itemB.name !== itemA.name)resultList.push(itemB);
     }
   }
 return resultList;  
}
```

or at the serverside (database):

```
select * from table_b where name not in (select name from table_a)
```

greetings

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should do that on the server side using `SQL` as already answered. However, since you ask about javascript. This is the way to filter it at client side:

```
//collect list of names in A
var table = document.getElementById("TableA");
var names = []
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    names.push(row.celss[1]);
}
//check names in B
table = document.getElementById("TableB");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    if(jQuery.inArray(row.cells[1], names) !== -1){
        //show row
    }else{
        //hide row
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have that much knowlwdge in Jquery..

But this query increases perfomance in a large DB.

```
SELECT
    FROM TableB
    LEFT JOIN TableA ON TableB.name=TableA.name   // id will be better than name
    WHERE TableB.name IS NULL
```

Hope this helps